# How to grep lines of an indented paragraph using regex?

Tags: regex, grep

I've got a docker-compose file, from which I want to extract it's environment variables within the section "environment:".

```
        image: non-important
        environment:
            DATABASE_URL: postgresql://localhost:5234
            REDIS_URL: 'redis://redis:6379'
            PRODUCTION_URL: 'http://localhost:4000'
            CLIENT_URL: 'http://localhost:3000'
            TOKEN_SEND_MODE: 'cookie|query_param'
        other_service:
            ...
```

Is there a way to grep only those variables, between "environment:" and "other_service:"?
The only big difference from the other lines is that they are more indented than others, but I don't know to differentiate them from the rest using a regex expression.

Comment: You might be a lot better off by using a YAML parser instead of trying to shoehorn this into grep. For example https://yq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `(?:^\t+environment:|\G(?!\A))[ \t]*[\r\n]+\t+\K([A-Z_]+:.*)` with `perl`

Comment: Maybe with `grep -P` some pattern that captures the indentation and matches consecutive lines with at least one more: [`^(\h+)environment:\h*(?:\r?\n\1\h.+)+`](https://regex101.com/r/GA38mj/1) (didn't try it).

Answer (score 1):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -0 -pe 's/.*(\n\s*DATABASE_URL:.*?)\bother_service:/$1/s' file
```

### Output

```
        DATABASE_URL: postgresql://localhost:5234
        REDIS_URL: 'redis://redis:6379'
        PRODUCTION_URL: 'http://localhost:4000'
        CLIENT_URL: 'http://localhost:3000'
        TOKEN_SEND_MODE: 'cookie|query_param'
```